# How to fill page with overlay

Tags: java, android

I have a `TRANSPARENT` overlay in my `android` app that when user click on it,it fade but it can't fill all activity like below image

[image]

MainActivity :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="This is Original View" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OverlayActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/over_lay_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#50220000" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="This is Overlay View" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView mOverLayImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Dialog overlayInfo = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    overlayInfo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    overlayInfo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    overlayInfo.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    overlayInfo.setContentView(R.layout.overlay_view);
    overlayInfo.show();

    mOverLayImage = (ImageView) overlayInfo.findViewById(R.id.over_lay_image);
    mOverLayImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            overlayInfo.cancel();
        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: you don't need to create another activity to make an overlay. use FrameLayout

Comment: @BojanKseneman : please show me a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your overlay activity, and inside your main activity apply this code :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="This is Original View" />

<!-- This is your overlay -->
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/over_lay_page"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/over_lay_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#50220000"
    android:onClick="clickedOverlay" />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="This is Overlay View" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I added a line on your `ImageView` which runs a function when clicked, now on your java file add this function:

```
//The onClick on xml requires a function of signature void(View) which is the clicked view (in this case the ImageView)
public void clickedOverlay(View view)
{
    //ImageView is clicked
    RelativeLayout rlLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.over_lay_page);
    rlLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This will make the `RelativeLayout` that contains the overlay views (including the `ImageView` which is clicked) to not only be invisible but not to interfere with anything. It also ignores input to it.

In case I misunderstood anything about your question feel free to correct me (I'm not sure I understood that completely).

Also if you want it to fade in or out or something like that you can do it with an `AlphaAnimation`.

Answer (score 2):

Use FrameLayout. Each item added to FrameLayout is on top of the previous one, like in this example the second TextView is on top of the frist one, but since it is not fully opaque, you can see them both!

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Blablabla"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#50220000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="I am on top"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now all you need to do is show/hide the overlayed items and you are good to go.